# CSS: text randomly appearing as italics, and <font-style: normal;> changes nothing

Tags: html, css, fonts

So my issue, I have an exercise  on lists and I'm doing and I exported the font Exo 2 from Google Fonts as such:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@300&display=swap');
}
```

But when I assigned the font to things like `h1` and `h2` and added `font-weight:500;` (Because otherwise the default `h1` font weight is far too heavy for the  style I'm doing), the font randomly turned *italics*. When I tried to force it back to normal using `font-style: normal;`, it just remained like that. The only way for it to not be italics is if I leave the default weight.

Why is this? How can I solve this?

MRE:

HTML

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@300&display=swap');
}
*{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}
h1,h2{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mugekenaga</h1>
<h2>Komeji</h2>
<ol>
    <li>Fomikatarye</li>
    <li>Domikatarye</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Try `!important;` and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

(Specify `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very top if you haven't)

Try importing the google fonts in this way:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

css

```
  *{font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;}
  h1,h2{font-size: 30px; font-weight: 300;}
```

html

```
<h2>Komeji</h2>
<ol>
    <li>Fomikatarye</li>
    <li>Domikatarye</li>
</ol>
```

Just a side note that depends on the browser you're using, sometimes for the h1~h* the numeric values for the font-weight might not be recognized.

I've tried this code on chrome and it seemed all the 100~900 font-weight worked fine. I'm putting the full code below for your convinience.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

    *{font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;}
    h1,h2{font-size: 30px; font-weight: 300;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Komeji</h2>
  <ol>
      <li>Fomikatarye</li>
      <li>Domikatarye</li>
  </ol>
</body>
</html>
```